# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '2 year -2 month 21 day' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to find out for how long employees have been working for the company and I should also find out if any of the employees have a resignation date.

But I don't have data for this right now, therefore value of this column in my database is Null. But i consider in my sql when it's happened take Resignation Date instead current time But for now take work start date and current time.  my theory is if the column resignation date is null, take "Current Date - Work start date", else
should it take resignation date - Work start date.

I wrote a SQL query for this theory and it's working fine but when I tried return for ex year month day for  how long employees working I got a problem which is:

a ) I struggled with this error for hours and I also tried convert those lines, I thought its should be converted but it's not working well so, when I run my main query, I get this error:

```
> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1  
> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '2 year -2 month 21 day' to data type int.
```

My main query looks like this:

```
**--- sql for how long employees work with year month day ----**
    CASE
        WHEN Users.ResignationDate IS NOT NULL 
           THEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, WorkStartDate, ResignationDate)
           ELSE CAST(DATEDIFF(yy, WorkStartDate, GETDATE()) AS varchar(4)) + ' year ' +
                CAST(DATEDIFF(mm, DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, WorkStartDate, GETDATE()), WorkStartDate), GETDATE()) AS varchar(2)) + ' month ' +
                CAST(DATEDIFF(dd, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, WorkStartDate, GETDATE()), WorkStartDate), GETDATE()), DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, WorkStartDate, GETDATE()), WorkStartDate)), GETDATE()) AS varchar(2)) +' day'  END as Ancinitet,
        Paychecks.DepartmentName AS Afdelinger
   FROM dbo.Paychecks INNER JOIN  dbo.Users ON Users.Id=Paychecks.UserId
WHERE Users.CustomerId=214 order by Users.FirstName;
```

Comment: I would suggest simplifying the query to isolate the problem.

Comment: i just edited the query , please take a look , if is not ok ,tell me

Comment: why you are showing different results for both cases - When resignation date is not null you are using datediff and when is null then you are adding year, month and days in your output.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago!) and its use is discouraged

Comment: @marc_s , thanks for your comment ,i wanna know , where you exactly mean in my code have old style or Can you please point me in the right direction.

Comment: @RyaN: this here: `FROM dbo.Paychecks, dbo.Users` - you should use  `FROM dbo.Paychecks p INNER JOIN dbo.Users u ON p.UserId = u.Id` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `case` expression returns a single value -- and a single type.  Yours is returning two different types, and SQL Server decides that the appropriate return type is the first one, an integer.

Just cast to a string:

```
(CASE WHEN Users.ResignationDate IS NOT NULL
      THEN CAST(DATEDIFF(YEAR, WorkStartDate, ResignationDate) as VARCHAR(255))
      ELSE (CAST(DATEDIFF(year, WorkStartDate, GETDATE()) AS varchar(4)) +' year ' +
            CAST(DATEDIFF(month, DATEADD(year, DATEDIFF(year, WorkStartDate, GETDATE()), WorkStartDate), GETDATE()) AS varchar(2)) +' month ' +
            CAST(DATEDIFF(day, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, DATEADD(year, DATEDIFF(year, WorkStartDate, GETDATE()), WorkStartDate), GETDATE()), DATEADD(year, DATEDIFF(yy, WorkStartDate, GETDATE()), WorkStartDate)), GETDATE()) AS varchar(2)) +' day'
          )
END) as Ancinitet,
```

I suspect there is a better way to do what you want.  If that is of interest, ask *another* question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: i just replaced the code ,you wrote it but i get this error : Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: What is the data type of `WorkStartDate`?

Comment: data type is datetime

Comment: `ResignationDate`?

Comment: also datetime for ResignationDate

Comment: The Code you wrote it , its work fine , i just tested every single line  to be sure , and i think there is something wrong with this line and i dont why ! : SELECT CASE 
WHEN Users.SSN IS NOT NULL THEN
DATEDIFF(YEAR,CONVERT(date,STUFF(LEFT(Users.SSN, 4), 3, 0, '.') + '.' + CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()) / 100 - 1 as char(2)) + SUBSTRING(Users.SSN, 5, 2), 104) , GETDATE()) 
ELSE
NULL
END As Aldre

Comment: Are you converting a Social Security Number to a date?  Is that the field you want to use?

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with this?

```
datediff(year, workStartDate, isNull(resignationDate, getDate()))
```

Comment: nothing wrong with that, i just wanna my out put look like this  for ex , 2 years 2 month 2 day

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off using weeks instead of months, since a week always contains 7 days.  You could also use a 30 day month which will generally get you close but your days may be off by a couple.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '20151115',
        @EndDate DATETIME = GETDATE();

SELECT  YearWeekDay = CONCAT(DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate) / 365, ' year ', DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate) % 365 / 7, ' week ',
                              DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate) % 365 % 7, ' day'
                            ),
        YearMonthDay = CONCAT(DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate) / 365, ' year ', DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate) % 365 / 30, ' month ',
                               DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate) % 365 % 30, ' day '
                             ),
        YWDHMS = CONCAT( DATEDIFF(SECOND, @StartDate, @EndDate) / 86400 / 365, 'y ', DATEDIFF(SECOND, @StartDate, @EndDate) / 86400 % 365 / 7, 'w ',
                         DATEDIFF(SECOND, @StartDate, @EndDate) / 86400 % 365 % 7, 'd ', DATEDIFF(SECOND, @StartDate, @EndDate) % 86400 / 3600, 'h ',
                         DATEDIFF(SECOND, @StartDate, @EndDate) % 3600 / 60, 'm ', DATEDIFF(SECOND, @StartDate, @EndDate) % 60, 's '
                       );
```

Output:

```
StartDate   EndDate                 YearWeekDay             YearMonthDay            YWDHMS
2015-11-15  2017-02-22 15:11:34.123 1 year 14 week 2 day    1 year 3 month 10 day   1y 14w 2d 15h 11m 34s
```

Comment: @RyaN Your accepted answer returns "2 year -9 month 8 day" for 11/15/2015.  Is that what you were wanting?  My answer returns "1 year 3 month 10 day" or "1 year 14 week 2 day".